# Why the jquery news ticker is not working on my website?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I added to my main page embed html and added this code/script:

```
<ul class="newsticker">
    <li>Etiam imperdiet volutpat libero eu tristique.</li>
    <li>Curabitur porttitor ante eget hendrerit adipiscing.</li>
    <li>Praesent ornare nisl lorem, ut condimentum lectus gravida ut.</li>
    <li>Nunc ultrices tortor eu massa placerat posuere.</li>
</ul>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/newsTicker.js"></script>

<script>
$('.newsticker').newsTicker();
</script>
```

Taken the code example from the owner site:

```
https://github.com/risq/jquery-advanced-news-ticker
```

Since my website edit is at weebly.com i uploaded already the js files.
I tried to change this line:

```
<script src="js/newsTicker.js"></script>
```

To:

```
<script src="/files/theme/jquery.newsTicker.js"></script>
```

Tried first theme:

Nothing was working so far.
I have this files on my site i have uploaded:

```
jquery.newsTicker.js
jquery.newsTicker.min.js
jquery.ticker.js
```

The script should make the text scrolling up. 
But it's not working. It does nothing i see the text static not moving.

EDIT

This is what i'm getting in the console:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://www.dragndropbuilder.com/files/theme/jquery.newsTicker
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'newsTicker' apps/customHtml.php?ucfid=838201711125452969&w=1395277796370&w=139527783313…2562870&w=1395292592083&w=1395292871153&w=1395292967301&w=1395292990574:56
6
Consider using 'dppx' units instead of 'dpi', as in CSS 'dpi' means dots-per-CSS-inch, not dots-per-physical-inch, so does not correspond to the actual 'dpi' of a screen. In media query expression: only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), not all, not all, not all, only screen and (min-resolution: 192dpi), only screen and (min-resolution: 2dppx) 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://www.dragndropbuilder.com/files/theme/jquery.newsTicker.js
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'newsTicker' customHtml.php?ucfid=838201711125452969&w=1395277796370&w=1395277833139&w=1395277850426&w=139527788…:56
```

Comment: What does your console say?

Comment: null how do i look the console ?

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+i in Chrome, Firebug if using Firefox or F12 tools in IE.

Comment: null i have updated my question now with what i'm getting in the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seem like the path to your plugin is incorrect, please check again or you can use direct link:

```
<script src="http://risq.github.io/jquery-advanced-news-ticker/assets/js/jquery.newsTicker.js"></script>
```

instead of:

```
<script src="/files/theme/jquery.newsTicker.js"></script>
```

as well as wrapping your jQuery code inside:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('.newsticker').newsTicker();
});
```

to prevent conflict in case you're using other javascript libraries.

Comment: Felix your solution is working. Maybe i am using javascript as well and there was a confilct.

Answer (score 0):

Go to firebug,

In the "Net" tab, check whether your plugin script js/css is getting included.

Make sure that it is not showing red.

Red means its not getting the correct path and hence a 404 error.

[image: Check if js file is included]

Comment: Programming Student yes i saw now in net tab somewhere a red 404 not found when i was using /files/themes....but once im using Felix solution there is no red. So maybe it is a confilct.

Answer (score 0):

By the way this plugin does not work with recent Jquery versions , works best with 1.6 .